# strange coeficient estimates in GLS with ranked variables

Tags: data-transformation, generalized-least-squares

Somebody could explain me why the estimated coefficients of a multiple regression through GLS seem not to pass through the majority of observations?

Here is a example:

```
require(nlme)
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(y=rank(rnorm(50,0)),x1=rank(y+rnorm(50,0))/2,x2=rank(y*2+rnorm(50,0)),x3=rank(rnorm(50,0)))
m=gls(y~x1+x2+x3,data=df)
ry=residuals(gls(y~x1+x2+x3,data=df))
rx=residuals(gls(x1~x2+x3,data=df))
plot(rx,ry)
abline(m$coefficients[1:2],col="blue")
    plot(df$x1,df$y)
    abline(m$coefficients[1:2],col="blue")
```

Comment: First, I think you changed the `seed` without changing the slope & intercept in the `abline` function. Otherwise, where did you come up with the "`a=29.887120,b=4.525572`"?

Comment: I ran your code but the output said that the intercept term was `30.017` and the slope coefficient for **x1** was `-0.150`. Does that sound right or am I missing something?

Comment: Try, for instance, running this instead: `abline(my.model$coefficients[1:2], col='blue', lwd=3)` (Oh, by the way, I saved **gls** output as 'my.model').

Comment: Done, but the problem was not that, it looks like the regression lines are always missing the data..

Comment: Well, they sort of *are* missing data since you have three predictors, **x1**, **x2**, & **x3**, but yet your plot regresses **y** on **x1** as if it were the only independent variable you were dealing with.

Comment: Thanks steve. In the first instance im plotting residuals of both, y and x1. I thought that would take that problem into account.

Comment: @steve. I created a new df with less noise in x1 and   x2.df=data.frame(y=rank(rnorm(50,0)),x1=rank(y/2),x2=rank(y*rnorm(50,0)),x3=rank(rnorm(50,0))). Now the lines seem more appropiated for the plot with original values than for the plot with residuals..I woudl expect the inverse would happen..